# C++ why do I only get the last line?

Tags: c++, cout

This is the text of my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string line;
    ifstream inf("grid.txt");
    while(!inf.eof()){
        getline(inf, line);
        cout << line;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(I'll be using sstream later)

This is the contents of `grid.txt`:

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

I'm compiling this under Cygwin and g++ and here's what I get:

```
$ g++ program.cpp
$ ./a.exe
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

To save you looking - that's the last line of the file. If I replace the loop with:

```
getline(inf, line);
cout << line;
getline(inf, line);
cout << line;
```

it will display not the first, but the second line of the file. It's been a while since I've last programmed in C++ but I'm 90% sure it's supposed to display more than one line there...

Comment: It works perfectly for me (using g++ under Fedora though).

Comment: Works for me. However, you should write `while (getline(...))`. Also note that `line` doesn't include the line separator itself, thus you should write `cout << line << endl;`.

Comment: @Philipp - "line" doesn't include the line separator itself -- bingo. It's outputting every line, but each line overwrites the previous since there is \r but no \n... Cygwin has some magic to munge text file line endings, too.

Comment: @jmanning2k: Interstingly it works when called from the Emacs minibuffer, but not when called from the Gnome terminal. But aniway it requires Windows-style line endings, otherwise nothing could ever be overwritten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding a `std::endl`, which will automatically append a newline and flush the buffer.

You can also use the `istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str, char delim );` signature to specify another delimiter than the default which is newline in case your file doesn't have any.

Answer (score 5):

What file format is your `grid.txt`? It's likely that your lines end with a carriage return `\r`

Just as I finished asking my question I tried:

```
cout << "hi";
```

before changing it to the two `cout`s. When I got two extra characters, that's when I realized I was getting the `\r` character. (Can you tell I've ran into problems with the carriage return before? :P )

Comment: I think you have the right answer. I just created a text file with `\r` line terminations and then the code just prints out the last line.

Comment: Indeed. Cygwin/g++ will assume Unix-style line endings (just `\n`), but if you created the file on Windows it might contain `\r` characters for compatibility with manual typewriters.

Comment: I've been bitten by the `\r` when I was doing some data mining for my CSCI 2 final project. It was easier to see then because the lines weren't the same length, but it was worse because I had no idea what char(13)/carriage return was. OTOH, cr's are terribly useful if you want one single line of changing data. I used that one a lot in my assembly class ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You're not emitting a newline at the end of the lines, so they're overwriting each other.

Change the output line to

```
cout << line << endl;
```

Comment: Why would the lines overwrite each other? They should just get written out as one long line. That's the output the OP's code produces on VS2008.

Comment: @Prae, because he's outputting carriage returns but not newlines.  Not sure if that's because the file is written that way, or if something is swallowing the newlines.

Comment: yes, if the file has `\r` line terminations `getline()` is reading the whole thing as one single line, including all the `\r`'s. Then, when you print it to the terminal it keeps jumping back to the beginning of the line every time it sees a `\r`. So you're right about the overwriting part, but your solution won't work because by the time you print that `endl` the damage is already done.

Comment: Although not ideal, the `endl` would work because the output will be pushed(`endl` also flushes) to the screen before the next `\r` has chance to overwrite the characters.

Answer (score -1):

You're reading binary data using getline. Try using read() instead.

Comment: It's not binary data, it's text digits

Comment: Is this not a hex dump? Sorry, my mistake